# Passing string variable in alert box

Tags: javascript, jsp, alert, scriptlet

I have below script where im passing scriptlet variable to javascript function. But there is no alert box displaying.. Please let me what im missing here..

```
<script language="JavaScript">
window.onload = function(){
    <%
      String res = request.getParameter("Message");
    %>
    var Value = "<%=res%>";
    alert(Value);
    document.Form.submit();
};
</script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: remove the double quotes if you want the script to run and print res inside of the value variable

Comment: Not a solution ! but for `script` tag `language` is an obsolete attribute; try using `type="text/javascript"` instead of `language="JavaScript"`

Comment: Thanks for the additional info, @Vishal

Comment: All, its not displaying the alert box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
<%
  String res = request.getParameter("Message");
%>
var Value = <%=res%>;
windows.alert(Value);
document.Form.submit();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to use is `<%= ... %>`. Try using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
<%
  String res = request.getParameter("Message");
%>
var Value = <%=res%>;
alert(Value);
document.Form.submit();
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

@John Why you creating scriptlet tag inside javascript. Instead try using this,

```
<%
String res = request.getParameter("Message");
%>
<script type="text/javaScript">
    window.onload = function(){

    var Value = "<%=res%>";
    alert(Value);
    document.Form.submit();
};
</script>
```

else try using jquery plugin for your purpose,

```
<%
    String res = request.getParameter("Message");
%>
<script type="text/javaScript">
   $(document).ready(function() {  
      var Value = "<%=res%>";
      alert(Value);
      $('form#myForm').submit();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable suggestion. the request parameter received has \n in it. and it causes the alert not displaying. once after removing that, its displaying now.. thanks